# Add elements to an array in MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

First of all, let me start by providing my MongoDB schema.

```
showTitle: String,
seasons: [{
  seasonNumber: String,
  episodes: [{
      episodeNumber: String,
      episodeTitle: String,
      episodeSynopsis: String
            }]  
         }]
```

The basic idea for this collection is to store tv show details. The TV shows can contain multiple seasons and each seasons contain multiple episodes.

I am allowing users to add additional seasons(only seasonNumber) at the client side. This will pass a value to the server side. This part works just fine as I can view the value, a string when I `console.log` at my server side.

Here, my API calls this particular function.

```
function saveReport(err, res, count, seasonId, seasonDetails)
{
  if(count == 0) //if 0 means not exist, so can add into DB
  {
    Show.update({_id: seasonId},{$push: {seasons:{seasonNumber: [seasonDetails]}}}, {upsert:true}, function(err, result)
    {
      console.log(result);
      res.json(result);
    });
  }
  else
  {
    res.json("TV Season already exists in MongoDB");
  }
}

module.exports.seasonsCreate = function(req, res)
{
  console.log("Calling the seasonsCreate function");
  var seasonId = req.params.id;
  var seasonDetails = req.body.season; //season number as a string(intended)

 //finding a specific showing using the id passed as parameter
 //$elemMatch is used to check if season number exists
 //using count to determine
  Show.findOne({_id: req.params.id, seasons: {$elemMatch: {seasonNumber: req.body.season}}}).count(function(err, count)
  {
    saveReport(err, res, count, seasonId, seasonDetails);
  });
}
```

I manually(using MongoDB command) added two seasons into MongoDB. Season 1 and Season 2 with 2 episodes each. However, when I try to add a 3rd episode via the client side, nothing happens. The exact result being returned is this:

> Object {ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0}

I've done updating before using a similar method. However, I'm a bit thrown off because this time I have nested arrays instead of just objects. I've also tried several combinations:

- with/without push
- with/without set
- with/without upsert

I'm pretty sure the problem is the way I am updating my database. Hope someone can shed some light here. Thanks !!

p/s: I'm using latest version of Mongoose.

Comment: That's a nested array. So the catch is you need to find "which" element of the outer array matches the to the one you want to update the inner array in. It's possible with `$push`, but other update operations are not so straightforward. I would strongly suggest to not use a nested array and figure a way to model differently.

Comment: @user3561036 do you have any suggestions on how I should model my schema then? I am new to this so any reading links would be helpful as well in terms of defining schema.

Comment: Why not loading the show and save it using the mongoose apis?

Comment: You might be better off asking a different question for that answer, explaining what you want to achieve from the data for reading and writing. Here the problem will be with the [positional `$` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) which can only match the index position of the "first" or "outer" array element to find in a query. A basic suggestion would be to "flatten" and include that "seasonNumer" in each episode entry

Comment: @B3rn475 that is something new to me, not really sure what you mean though. it would really be helpful if you could share some links to reading materials regarding what you're talking about so I could read more on that. thanks !!

Comment: @B3rn475 Because that sucks in a nutshell. You are reading an object from the database, making changes offline and then writing it back. Leads to data inconsistency everywhere.

Comment: @user3561036 It is not different from what is actually happening, no one garantees you that nothing happens between the count and the update. Starting from your assumption no ORM o ODM should be used at all. So just remove mongoose and go for plain MongoDB Connection

Comment: @B3rn475 It's worlds of difference. `$push` will append to whatever content is in the array on update. What you are suggesting will **overwrite** any changes that were issued in between the `.find()` and the `.save()`

Comment: @user3561036 and B3rn475, thanks for your suggestions guys. I manage to get it to work, apparently I've been using pushAll all this while. I'll definitely work on improving my schema model though. sorry for the trouble and thanks again !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I'm sensing dangerously bad advice issuing from people telling you to `.find()` the data then `.save()` it I'll explain the basic case of "flattening" the data in order to avoid the nested array issue.

Nested arrays suffer from a problem that the [positional `$` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) you would need to use to match the index of the required array element to update can only reference the "outer" array element. While this might be fine to identify that element and "push" to an inner array of that element, it is just not possible to get the position of the inner element if you wanted to update that inner element.

So the idea here is to "not nest arrays", and structure so you can actually efficiently update within the available constraints.

A better structure would be:

```js
showTitle: String,
episodes: [{
  seasonNumber: String,
  episodeNumber: String,
  episodeTitle: String,
  episodeSynopsis: String
}]
```

Now you don't really loose anything here, and it's just a little extra duplication of data, but at a small cost.

To add to the array:

```js
Show.update({ "_id": showId },{ "$push": { "episodes": episodeData } },callback)
```

To update an element:

```js
Show.update(
    { 
       "_id": showId,
       "episodes": { 
           "$elemMatch": {
               "seasonNumber": season,
               "episodeNumber": episode
           }
       }
    },
    { "$set": { "episodes.$": episodeData } },
    callback
)
```

Or even:

```js
Show.update(
    { 
       "_id": showId,
       "episodes": { 
           "$elemMatch": {
               "seasonNumber": season,
               "episodeNumber": episode
           }
       }
    },
    { "$set": { "episodes.$.episodeSynopsis": synopis } },
    callback
)
```

And if you just wanted all episodes for a season:

```js
Show.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": { "_id": showId, "epsisodes.seasonNumber": seasonNumber } },
        { "$redact": {
            "if": { 
                "$eq": [
                    { "$IfNull": [ "$seasonNumber", seasonNumber ] } },
                    seasonNumber
                ]
            },
            "then": "$DESCEND",
            "else": "$PRUNE"
        }}
    ],
    callback
)
```

Which will cull any unmatched entries from the array as it is returned in the query.

So you can do just about everything you want with little fuss in changing the data storage, and with atomic updates that cannot run into problems with other operations changing the data into an unexpected state as you run the risk from otherwise.

Comment: As a complement to this excellent clarification, worth mentioning the [SERVER-831](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831) proposal to enhance the positional operator `$` for nested arrays.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I'd applaud that except it is issue `831` so not exactly a new request. Nonetheless it can't hurt for more people up-voting that issue. Is there a magic number of up-votes that make this a top priority :)

Comment: This will definitely solve all my future problems. Thanks  @user3561036 !!